# How to prevent MongoDB bulk insertion from skipping the rest when one fails

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bulkinsert

I'm using MongoDB bulk insertion with `{ordered: false}` option. This is supposed to make sure that one error won't result in rest of the items in the same batch failing together.

But it doesn't seem to be working. When one of the items fail (for example, because the document size is too large, etc.), the rest of the items in the same batch get ignored altogether.

Is there some way to make sure that if one item fails insertion, the rest are safely inserted? By the way I'm using Node.js

Comment: `ordered: false` is the right solution, but my guess is it doesn't work with all exceptions, but only bypasses index-related bugs.

Comment: how do i handle large data exception?

Comment: Share your code/query

Comment: What is the version of your mongDB and the operation you are using?